# For item in array loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In pure JavaScript is it possible to create a loop in the form of

```
for item in array
{
  alert(item)
  // do stuff
}
```

instead of

```
for (var i = 0;  i < array.length; i++)
{
  alert(array[i])
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `for..of`

Comment: [`for ... of` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a `let...of` loop

```
for (let item of array) {
  alert(item);
}
```

Another option would be to use a `forEach` loop

```
array.forEach(function(item){
   alert(item);
});
```

You can [find more information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Should you not mark it as duplicate instead? This is very basic question.

Comment: I will do! @Rajesh i have never really marked a question as a duplicate before! will do it now :-)

Comment: @Rajesh someone else has already done so! :-)

Comment: Point is this is our portal and its our responsibility to keep it clean. Marking answer as duplicate will make sure, someone  searching for such query gets enough information. For example, there is `for...of` that is more suited for this question but since it is not described here, people will not know about it. Also there are many details that could help if you mark duplicate and also keep one collective post. So please next time if you see such basic question, do mark it duplicate. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh will do! thanks!